# Is there a way to left align my YAML heading which includes title,author, and date

Tags: r, yaml, text-alignment

```
  ---
title: "`r params$id`"
author: "`r params$first` `r params$last`"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%b %d, %Y')`"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
html_document: default
params:
  id: 1
  first: MICHAEL
  last: JORDAN
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{tabu}
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{threeparttablex}
- \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{xcolor}

---
```

My YAML as it is provides my title, author, and date in the ceter. I want to left align the heading. Is there a way?

Comment: Maybe this blog entry helps: https://www.gerkelab.com/blog/2019/04/manipulating-latex-in-rmd/.  "Modifying R Markdown's LaTeX styles
How to make a simple LaTeX template for R Markdown from scratch". [Only for PDF output]